# Close modal dialog with returning a value in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to close the modal dialog with return a value in a same function

I cannot write code as follow,because when a returning a value, next line never be excuted,

```
function butOK_OnClick() {
    return "OK";
    window.close();
}
```

so is this the right way ?

```
function butOK_OnClick() {
    window.returnvalue = "OK";
    window.close();
}
```

or what is the best way to do this ?

Comment: PopUp? You using a modal dialog?

Comment: Are you just trying to run a function when the popup closes?

Comment: thats my mistake. yes, thats the modal dialog

Comment: I need to return a value when closing a modal dialog

Comment: If you want to return a value calculated in the other window to the main window (from which the popup opened), do `window.opener.[...] = [...]` before closing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using `window.showModalDialog` to open the window (since `window.open` does not allow for return values), you'd just set the `returnValue` property of the modal and then set it to a variable in the opener.

Opener window:

```
var returnedValue = window.showModalDialog(url);
```

Modal window:

```
window.returnValue = 'foo';
window.close();
```

Comment: Assuming you assign the return value correctly in the opener window, yes.

Comment: yes. thank you very much. can you tell me any idea about next answer

Comment: @MaduraHarshana I'm not sure what you mean, what next answer?

Comment: I meant the second answer, that you are commented on. it this support jquery, is that correct ?

Comment: Deprecated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20733962/why-is-window-showmodaldialog-deprecated-what-to-use-instead

Answer (score -1):

you can use,

```
$("#modalId", window.top.document).data("cancelled", true);
$("#modalId", window.top.document).data("returnValue", returnVal);
```

Comment: There's no jQuery mentioned or tagged in this question.