# Why is window.showModalDialog deprecated? What to use instead?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, privileges, window.open, showmodaldialog

I was developing a GreaseMonkey script which used `window.showModalDialog`.

But before finishing it, I have discovered that Firefox 29 warns:

> Use of window.showModalDialog() is deprecated. Use window.open()
>   instead. For more help
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open

But the problem is that `window.open` needs `UniversalBrowserWrite` privilege in order to open a modal window using `window.open`.

Then, why is `window.showModalDialog` deprecated? Is there any API which doesn't require privileges?

**Note**: I don't want a **fake** modal dialog (like jQuery's one), I need a **real** modal which pauses JavaScript execution.

Comment: Read: [window.showModalDialog: What It is and Why You Should Never Use It](http://tjvantoll.com/2012/05/02/showmodaldialog-what-it-is-and-why-you-should-never-use-it/), [dev.opera: Removing showModalDialog from the Web platform](http://dev.opera.com/blog/showmodaldialog/)

Comment: "I need a real modal which pauses JavaScript execution." Window.showModalDialog() is depreciated precisely because it pauses javascript execution. Pausing javascript execution is difficult to implement securely, and in a way the gives a responsive browser. This is similar to why synchronous XMLHttpRequest is also being depreciated.

Answer (score 30):

**Why is window.showModalDialog deprecated?**

From http://tjvantoll.com/2012/05/02/showmodaldialog-what-it-is-and-why-you-should-never-use-it/,

> In general the idea of putting a native dialog implementation into the
>   browser was a really good idea, but `window.showModalDialog` was a bad
>   implementation that is riddled with issues and poor browser support. (...)
>
> Note that (...) [a modal dialog using `showModalDialog`] is a full HTML
>   document, not a snippet that is injected in. This is a characterizing
>   feature of `window.showModalDialog`. It’s really just two completely
>   separate windows communicating with each other. The fact that you have
>   two separate windows and DOMs means you don’t have to worry about JS &
>   DOM conflicts, which is appealing if you have a lot of bad JavaScript
>   with a cluttered global scope. But mostly this just adds unnecessary
>   complexity, complicates the browser implementation, and contributes to
>   a number of bugs. (...)
>
> While it’s important that modal dialogs prevent the user from
>   interacting with the originating window, there’s no reason the user
>   shouldn’t be allowed to interact with other tabs or native browser
>   controls (back/forward, favorites, address bar, etc). (...) This is
>   actually a big annoyance to the end user. (...)
>
> The debugging experience for `window.showModalDialog` is horrible.
>   (...) You're basically forced to alert like it’s 1999 to determine
>   what’s going on. (...)
>
> Currently no major mobile browsers support `window.showModalDialog`,
>   so if you’re looking for any sort of tablet / mobile support you need
>   to stay away.

**What to use instead?**

HTML5 introduces the new [`<dialog>`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/interactive-elements.html#the-dialog-element) element, which can be used to display dialogs, including modal ones.

For example:

```html
<dialog id="myDialog">
    Foo bar
    <button id="hide">Close</button>
</dialog>
<button id="show">Show Dialog</button>
```

```js
var dialog = document.getElementById('myDialog');  
document.getElementById('show').onclick = function() {  dialog.showModal();  };  
document.getElementById('hide').onclick = function() {  dialog.close();      };
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/grj4x5k9/)

The problems are:

- Browser support is currently negligible, but there is a [polyfill](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/dialog-polyfill).
- It doesn't [pause](http://www.w3.org/TR/html/webappapis.html#pause) JS execution.

Answer (score 6):

You can use my [showModalDialog polyfill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25130996/912946) using `<dialog>` tag if you want to still use this solution.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, if you don't want to use privileges and want to use modal window, best way is to use [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) or something similar.

Comment: But jQuery's modal dialog is called *modal* but it isn't *modal*. I need to stop JavaScript execution.

Comment: @Oriol why would you want js execution to pause? Can't you just not do anything until a callback is called?

Comment: In my previos project, I have a same issue with window.open() and privileges. Because of that we have decided to use jQuery. For preventing execution of js, I can suggest trow() function or somthing like that.

Comment: @megawac Because the javascript I want to pause is not mine, is untrusted javascript from sites (I use it in a GreaseMonkey script). With `showModalDialog` I can pause it and let the user decide if it should be killed or not. If user decides it's not bad, then the script can continue.

Comment: @AshotSeropian Well, I meant "pause" instead of "stop"

Comment: Can you apply jQuery's when() and then() methods for simulating some kind of "pause"?

Comment: @AshotSeropian No, because I don't have control over the code I want to pause.

Comment: I'm using the jquery ui method with an iframe that I set the dialogArguments property of from the parent. Any code that was previously executing after the return from showModalDialog, and is based on the popups return value, I changed to be inside an anonymous function that I pass to my dialog method as a callback to execute when the dialog closes. Inside the close event handler of the dialog, I extract whats in the returnValue property. This way the page in the dialog, along with the code that was previously paused, doesn't require any modifications.

Comment: @Oriol It sounds like what you're trying to do should be written as a full fledged browser extension, and not as a GreaseMonkey script.  Javascript that stops and restarts other javascript sounds pretty dangerous (all inside of javascript).

Comment: @Kiquenet I didn't find any alternative which pauses JS. Other than that you can use `<dialog>` elements or jQuery ones.

Comment: @Oriol maybe too late response. Modal dialogs have nothing to do with internal program execution pausing. They may be related, but only due to specific implementation.

Answer (score -1):

To block script execution, use `while (true) { }`. The fact that this is equivalently bad behavior to `showModalDialog` is part of the reason they removed `showModalDialog`.

Also, "modal" and "blocking script execution" are not the same thing. "Modal" simply means on top of everything else, preventing you from interacting with those things. So jQuery UI dialogs are modal, they just don't block script execution.

Comment: Uhm, but `while (true) { }` is CPU intensive, isn't it? And if I do that, the page (or even the browser) will freeze, so the dialog will be unusable too. I want to pause only the page, not the dialog.

Comment: You can't to stop this loop execution, because js is one-threaded. Opened with `window.open` windows still use same thread, and will be full frozen(you probably even never see them)