# showmodal dialog suddenly giving undefined in chrome

Tags: javascript, html

I have a the following script as below.

```
$('.t1 span.droppable').each(function(){
                //alert("DROP");
                //$(this).droppable();
        $('.droppable').droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {


    var fromd = 0;
    var tod = 0;
    var url1 = "insertsw.php?fromd=" + fromd + "&tod=" + tod;
    var r = "";
    objArgs = new Array(tpFrom, sFrom, nsdFrom, tpTo,sTo, dTo);
    r=showModalDialog(url1,objArgs,"dialogWidth: 450; dialogHeight: 300; resizable: yes");

   if(r==null)
                {
                    popUpOpen=1;
                }
                else
                {
                    popUpOpen=1;
                //alert("R : "+r);
                var n=r.split("#");
                }
   }
 }
}
```

It have been working for almost 3 years on chrome and suddenly now it shows undefined. But works fine on firefox perfectly as usual. What changes have chrome done for me to adapt to it ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's your issue:
http://windowsitpro.com/blog/google-kills-showmodaldialog-api-chrome-37-and-does-evil-exchange-owa

Here are some workarounds:
[Why is window.showModalDialog deprecated? What to use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20733962/why-is-window-showmodaldialog-deprecated-what-to-use-instead)

EDIT:

take a look at this package: [showModalDialog](https://github.com/niutech/showModalDialog)

You shouldn't need to change very much to get this package to work with yours. It's virtually the same syntax.

For example, you can do:

```
window.showModalDialog("demo-modal.html", "some arguments", "dialogWidth:500px;dialogHeight:200px");
```

Which is virtually the same as what you currently have. See if just including the package fixes it. I believe it should. There doesn't seem to be a different syntax at all, and this should work in chrome

Comment: Ok I run this r = showModalDialog(url1,objArgs,""); but the error is still there only think the window now shrink

Comment: hmm, honestly i cant tell whats going on without more information, sorry

Comment: Ok benderman I removed this line throw 'Execution stopped until showModalDialog is closed'; and there is no error. But when I press the button Add I got this codes window.returnValue=Number(rFromControl.value)+"#"+Number(rToControl.value);
    window.close(); which now it does not close the window

Comment: what do you have a custom close button? or are you talking about the one in the top hand corner

Comment: I have custom close box which first I do a javascript validation all the fields have been filled then only finally I call this codes window.returnValue=Number(rFromControl.value)+"#"+Number(rToControl.value); window.close(); . Another thing I notice when I press the button I get this error now Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } referring to eval('{\n' + nextStmts.join('\n'));

Comment: You'll need to use jquery or document.getelemrnt to get the dialog and then call close on that element to close it

Comment: Do you mean something like this document.getelementByID("dialog").close(); How about passing by my return value ?

Comment: Put it in the parens for close

Comment: I have put this parent.document.getElementById("dialog").close();gives me cannot read property close. Another think in the pop-up window I have also include reference to javascript should I remove it or leave it? Lastly how to past back my pop-up value to my parent window

Comment: "Dialog" isn't it's id is it? Inspect the element on the page. You shouldn't need another reference to JavaScript I don't think. Not sure what you mean In the last question

Comment: I got this in the inspect element <dialog style="Width:300px;Height:350px" open=""><a href="#" id="dialog-close" style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 4px; font-size: 20px; color: #000; text-decoration: none; outline: none;">×</a><iframe id="dialog-body" src="insert.php?fromd=0&amp;tod=0" style="border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe></dialog>. So how to close on my custom button. what I mean by my last question is  how to return this both values window.returnValue=Number(rFromControl.value)+"#"+Number(rToControl.value);

Comment: My problem now is to close using my custom button and pass back the value to the calling window. So I am just left with these 2 problems.

Comment: You should be able to do .close(returnVal). As for the close button do something like document.getelementsbytag("dialog")[0].close()

Comment: I tried this document.getElementsByTagName("dialog")[0].close(); but it gives me cannot read property close of undefined.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61406/discussion-on-answer-by-benderman-showmodal-dialog-suddenly-giving-undefined-in).

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
    if(no_support_dialog()){
       showModalDialog(url1,objArgs,"dialogWidth: 450; dialogHeight: 300; resizable: yes");
    }else{
       alert('This browser does not support the native method \'showModalDialog\'');
    }

    function no_support_dialog() {
        return (/\{\s*\[native code\]\s*\}/).test('' + window.showModalDialog);
    }
```