# Get value passed in showmodeldialog

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How can i retrieve the value passed in `window.showmodeldialog()` using `Request.params` ?

```
 var ddValue = $("#ddFrequency").val();
            alert(ddValue);
            window.showModalDialog("MS_RIT_SmartCalendarPopUp.aspx",ddValue, "dialogHeight: 700px;)
```

Now I want to access this **"ddvalue"** on server side ?

Comment: this method of showing a modal is deprecated see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20733962/why-is-window-showmodaldialog-deprecated-what-to-use-instead