# ShowModalDialog is not working in latest firefox version 56

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, showmodaldialog

showModalDialog was perfectly working in firefox, Since the latest version of firefox deprecated showModaldialog - ShowModalDialog is throwing up the error

TypeError: dialog.showModal is not a function

Is there any fix to support ShowModalDialog in latest firefox version similar to Chrome? http://niutech.github.io/showModalDialog/demo.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is window.showModalDialog deprecated? What to use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20733962/why-is-window-showmodaldialog-deprecated-what-to-use-instead)

Comment: tl;dr use https://github.com/GoogleChrome/dialog-polyfill